# count occurrences across columns and match to ID column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, match

I have a df of 100+ columns and not all are filled

```
> head(othertopics,20)
# A tibble: 20 x 118
   Q6    Q10.1 Q10.2 Q10.3 Q10.4 Q10.5 Q10.6 Q10.7 Q10.8 Q10.9 Q10.10 Q10.11 Q10.12 Q10.13
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
 1 52    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA    
 2 294   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA    
 3 103   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA    
 4 52    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA    
 5 87    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA    
 6 52    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA    
 7 136   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA    
 8 19    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA    
 9 19    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA    
10 0     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA    
11 0     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA    
12 19    NA    NA    NA    4     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA    
13 52    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA    
14 108   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA
```

Q6 is an ID.
across Q10.1 to Q10.117 there are different values assigned for each ID (see line 12).
Using unlist i used unlist and managed to get the frequency for every time a value was mentioned among the 117 columns. But i need to match them to their respective ID.
So basically i need to match an ID col with 117 columns and get the frequency of each column.

```
othertopics<-data.frame(table(unlist(TableTopic2[,22:138])))
```

```
    Var1 Freq                                                           
    10    1
    100    4                                                                                    
    101    1                                                                                  
    102   12                                                                                      
    103    7
    104   21                                                                             
    105   36                                                                         
    106    1
```

```
so for example variable 105 appeared 36 times across 17 values of IDs on column Q6( This number I counted on Excel).
So, so far I only have the first half of my solution as i need to know what is the ID associated with the variables . ( ie: the 17 values i counted)
also note that the variable columns contain the number of their variable, So for example row Q10.105 is for variable 105 which has a frequency of 36.

I hope i was able to make it clear.

Thanks!
```

Answer (score 1):

This question is not particularly clear, but I'll do my best. I think the way to tidy this data is to pivot all of the non-id columns to one column (I call it 'col_name') and then have another column with all of the values (mostly NA's; I call it 'numbered_var' for numbered variable). Then, you can aggregate based on the numbered_variable column.

This example is obviously not reproducible, so I constructed a simplified version of your data (I think):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- tibble(
    id = 1:5,
    Q1 = c(NA_integer_, 10L, NA_integer_, 10L, NA_integer_),
    Q2 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 11L, NA_integer_, 11)
)
```

It looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 5 × 3
     id    Q1    Q2
  <int> <int> <dbl>
1     1    NA    NA
2     2    10    NA
3     3    NA    11
4     4    10    NA
5     5    NA    11
```

Next, I use `tidyr::pivot_longer()` to put the column names containing Q into a column, with their associated value in another column:

```
df <- pivot_longer(
        df,
        cols = contains("Q"), # you will want to use this, but first remove the Q from the id column name in your data
        names_to = "col_name",
        values_to = "numbered_var"
)
```

This makes the data long:

```
# A tibble: 10 × 3
      id col_name numbered_var
   <int> <chr>           <dbl>
 1     1 Q1                 NA
 2     1 Q2                 NA
 3     2 Q1                 10
 4     2 Q2                 NA
 5     3 Q1                 NA
 6     3 Q2                 11
 7     4 Q1                 10
 8     4 Q2                 NA
 9     5 Q1                 NA
10     5 Q2                 11
```

You should still probably have three columns, but the id's would repeat themselves *n*-column times, just as they repeat twice for the two columns here.

Next, I would group by the variables, which seem to be of interest, and list the unique id's that have the variables in a new column:

```
df <- group_by(df, numbered_var)
df <-   summarize(
        df,
        var_appearances = n(),
        ids = list(unique(id))
    )
```

Now, the data frame looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  numbered_var var_appearances ids      
         <dbl>           <int> <list>   
1           10               2 <int [2]>
2           11               2 <int [2]>
3           NA               6 <int [5]>
```

That `ids` column is a list-column with a vector of `id`s:

```
print(df$ids)
[[1]]
[1] 2 4

[[2]]
[1] 3 5

[[3]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

I'm not sure this is exactly what you'll be able to do, but hopefully it sets you in the right direction.